# Can I delete the gradle folder from Android Studio project safely?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a folder named ".gradle" which is taking 600MB of space.
Normally, it contains a file named fileSnapshots.bin, which is around 20 MB.
But for one of my apps there are several sub folders in which there are several fileSnapshots.bin files created and these are around 150-200MB each.

Please see the following screenshot and tell me if I can delete this folder after closing my project?
If I delete it will my project rebuild safely next time?

[image]

Comment: Inside .gradle folder you can find all settings and other files used by gradle to build the project. You can delete these files without problems. Gradle will recreate it.But it seems your gradle taking too much space you need to varify what data stored inside it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the project you can find the .gradle folder.

Inside you can find all settings and other files used by gradle to build the project. You can delete these files without problems. Gradle will recreate it.

Also these file are not committed and Version Control Systems. It means that when you checkout the project these files are not present on the project.

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765386/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-gradle-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks bro now I can save a lot of space :)

Answer (score 3):

You can safely delete all, but you should keep at least 4.1, assuming that is what `gradle.properties` is using.

You could also prevent this directory from being created for all projects by installing Gradle yourself externally from Android Studio, and configuring it use that instead of Gradle Wrapper.