# Can i delete my gradle folders?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Can i delete the older versions of the gradle folder versions such as 2.0, 3.3 and just keep the latest version or are all of them required by Android Studio?? [click to see all the gradle folders under wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrhhP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to delete the .gradle folder in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765386/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-gradle-folder-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Lucem It is not a duplicate (at least not to the linked question). The linked question is about the folders under `.gradle` in the project directory, this one is about the Gradle version cache used by the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is simply a cache.**

You can always delete the downloaded Gradle versions, as the Gradle wrapper will redownload them if required.

However, if you don't necessarily need space on your disk, you can also keep them, so that they can be reused whenever a Gradle project with the specific version is executed. This way, you may save the time to redownload.