# AndroidStudio gradle and class broke

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

So I opened my android studio to find this message

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file '(my build gradle)' from cache.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:75)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:68)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$400(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:51)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:102)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:59)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\Users\rafaw\OneDrive\Desktop\pp_rafa\pp_rafa\remindertest\app\build.gradle' from cache.
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler$ClassesDirCompiledScript.loadClass(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:333)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.getScript(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:55)
  at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:86)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
  at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
  at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:723)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:150)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:69)
  at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
  at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:164)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:71)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
  at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:90)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
```

Along with that I found

```
Unable to load class 'build_9ox44yv7hgyib8h2by1qfwuux'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Do you guys know how to fix this? Invalidate cache and restart doesn't work and sync project with gradle files doesn't either. Also the majority of the problems mainly resides in Activity 2. Local history also doesn't work. Do I have to restart everything?

Comment: Also I couldn't fit all the exception bugs as it was too much

Comment: Close Android Studio and delete the `.gradle` folder entirely?

Comment: in the folder of the project?

Comment: Yeah - it is [safe to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50903926/9473786) and will re-download a bunch of stuff when you launch Android Studio again.

Comment: it does not work it gives the same message

Comment: No idea then...

Answer (score 1):

update here. After trying a lot of things, such as invalidate cache, restarting, deleting .gradle, etc. After a couple of minutes of messing around I saw a new message different from before on the problems which was compileSDKversion could not be found. I checked the buildgradle.app and I found that it was already there, I searched about it and found that usually there was a buildToolsVersion below it. I added it and somehow it worked. Perhaps it wasn't that that fixed it but it worked out in the end. It could be me restarting it a lot or something.